# "Results not announced yet" vs "Results not yet announced"

Tags: meaning

> 1. Results not announced yet
> 2. Results not yet announced

Which of the two is the correct one, and what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Are these sentences to be used on their own, for example as a note on a notice board where exam results will soon be posted, or as part of a complete sentence?.

Comment: Used on their own

Answer (score 2):

Your two examples and your reply to my question are in [Telegram Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_style).  Both of these sentences can be de-telegramised to make grammatically correct sentences:

> The results have not been announced yet.
>
> The results have not yet been announced.

Expanded in this way, there is no difference in meaning between the two sentences.

Comment: Good to know the "Telegram Style" but your link is broken by the accidental inclusion of the trailing period

Comment: Actually, it was @temp8jfhfhf ... I just needed to improve his/her edit because of the 6 character limit.